# Webbrowser.open error 'could not locate runnable browser'

Tags: python, macos

Im trying to use the web browser module for the first time in Python. After importing it and running the 'webbrowser.open' command plus the url it just returns 'True' and nothing opens. I tried this in both Python 2.7 and 3.4.3, Im on a Mac with Safari and Chrome installed.

I did some poking around here and elsewhere on the web and tried some other commands from the docs such as:

```
webbbrowser._tryorder
```

which returns:

```
['MacOSX', 'firefox', 'safari']
```

and then

```
webbrowser.items
```

which returns:

```
dict_items([('macosx', [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at        0x107f1d8d0>]), ('firefox', [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at   0x107eed6d8>]), ('safari', [None, <webbrowser.MacOSXOSAScript object at 0x107eedba8>])])
```

and then finally I tried using the path to safari as follows:

```
webbrowser.get('/Applications/Safari/Contents/MacOS/Safari').open('http://www.google.com')
```

and this returns an error saying it can't locate a runnable browser

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File     "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/webbrowser.py", line 51, in get
raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

Ive done a fair bit of searching on the web and haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem, can anyone help?

Please note Im still a fairly green Python and Mac user.

Comment: So `webbrowser.get('MacOSX').open('http://www.google.com')` doesn't work?

Comment: no, it just returns 'True'